# RTSP Proxy for local accessed content archive

Tags: proxy, server, rtsp

I have local access from one computer to RTSP server by my ISP which is delivering IPTV content archive (timeshift). RTSP is avilable only from this computer because it has correctly configured internet access to the server. Because I would like to watch the content of this RTSP server on every device at home, I'd like to create local server which would accept connections and just transfer data from the end server (by ISP) to client.

I already tried to configure Live555 RTSP Proxy, but it's not really the right software which would enable me what I need. Another thing I tried out is Darwin Streaming Server, but I think it wouldn't support the format of IPTV content archive. What do I actually need?

Link to ISP's content archive looks like: `rtsp://archive.my-isp.tld:554/programme_id_channel.ts`.
I would like to access to the same stream via `rtsp://IP-of-my-computer:port/programme_id_channel.ts`.

Is there any software which is acting like proxy and it would be possible to set it to my needs? I would really appreciate any answer and help.

P.S.: Type of ISP's stream is MPEG TS.

EDIT: I already tried out [node-ffmpeg-mpegts-proxy](https://github.com/Jalle19/node-ffmpeg-mpegts-proxy) and it works good for approximately 10 seconds, then I got some error from avconv about RTSP packet loss and stream stops. I would also need an option to seek video to wanted destination and with current setup (default options of avconv) of node-ffmpeg-mpegts-proxy. For the start I need something that will successfully stream video from source to destination.

Comment: Can you answer these questions: What is the configuration that enables your computer to access the RTSP server? What is the problem with LIVE555 Proxy Server?

Comment: @simurg Configuration which I mentioned in the beginning of question refers to VLAN and static routes, which I need to set because the stream is only available on separated network by ISP. I can't do that on all computers and phones, since some of them are "locked" and it's not possible to add VLAN and routes. Problem with Live555 Proxy Server is that it doesn't support dynamic proxying of content (you need to enter all streams which you want proxy at the beginning of starting the proxy server) - I know, I can change source code, but ... I also didn't have any success on ...

Comment: ... accessing the stream which was forwarded by proxy.
@Max As far as I know it is. Why? Because I'm paying for that services and ISP also provided some info on how to access those streams.